# Conditional HTML table td cell

Tags: html, css, django

I have the following HTML table td with Django tags.  If the value of the tag is false I want the td value to be a red 'X' image.  If the value of the tag is true I want the td value to be a green check image.  Does anybody have any simple examples that will help me out?

```
{% for sport in all_sports %}
    <tr class="sportrow {% cycle '' 'altrow' %}">
        <td><a href="show/{{ sport.id }}">></a></td>
        <td>{{ sport.skill }}</td>
        <td>{{ sport.skilllevel }}</td>
        <td>{{ sport.yearswithsport }}</td>
        <td>{{ sport.certified }}</td>
        <td>{{ sport.new }}</td>

    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Which tag are you referring to that will have the true/false value?

Answer (score 0):

you didn't exactly specified which field is your BooleanField but assuming that you have a field `{{ sport.certified }}` which returns value of either True or False then you can simply use if statement in your template like below:

```
<td>{% if sport.certified %} {{ sport.certified }} {% else %} X---X {% endif %}</td>
```

In your template if value of `sport.certified` is `False` then `X---X` part of the template will be rendered which can be any text, link or image anything that you want to keep.

Note: you can also use if block inside tag to set conditional css class or style

Answer (score 0):

You would do like this, substituting my_thing.my_value for whatever condition you are testing:

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/img/icon-{{ my_thing.my_value|yesno:'yes,no,unknown' }}.svg" alt="{{ my_thing.my_value|yesno:'yes,no,unknown' }}">
```